# Java zero matrix memory usage

Tags: java

i have been struggling to understand the following question.

Is zero-matrix necessarily memory efficient? does zero-matrix cost less memory (or does it not cost any memory)?

I tried to verify it in java but it turns out the memory has been allocated for the specified size.

I am not sure about C/C++ or other language like matlab and octave and how they manage the matrix and vector memory;

The reason why i am asking this is want to build a sparse matrix with huge size, but most of entries are zeros, it turns out that java is not a good choice, because zero-matrix in java still cost much memory. Does any one have any experience with this problem? not sure how you deal with it, your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Directly allocating an empty array in any language is going to take that much memory.  You should probably be using a data structure specifically designed for sparse arrays or matrices, regardless of language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward zero-filled matrix will cost you in any language: the amount allocated does not depend on what numbers you fill it with.

Take a look at e.g. [UJMP](http://ujmp.org/) that provides sparse matrices support, and many algorithms. Probably other implementations exist.

In general, if you find something to be difficult to implement but likely useful, google for open-source libraries. Chances are many wheels have been invented already.

Comment: thanks a lot 9000, will take a closer look at the UJMP, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to allocate space for your matrix, it will take space independently of which numbers it will hold. (Even if null).

However I can imagine that someone somewhere has designed a data structure to handle this.

First thing that pops up in my mind is that you could create a data structure which holds positions with its according value. If you were to ask for the value at a given position that doesn't exist, you could return 0. Of course this would be inefficient for small matrices or matrices with only a few zeroes. Just an idea.